# creating scrollable spinner to show some items

Tags: android, android-spinner

i used spinner to show items but it only works when the items are less than 5 items, and when i want to show 10 items this error happens : unfortunately stopped :( how can i use scrollable spinner to show all items in the spinner
here is:
spinner.xml :and main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shw"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:text="which"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt1help2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt3"
    android:text="ok"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2help2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="no"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_style"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />
```

```
final Dialog dl = new Dialog(Main.this);

            dl.setContentView(R.layout.spinner);

            dl.setTitle("show");
            TextView txt2 = (TextView) dl.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
            TextView txt3 = (TextView) dl.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
            ///تنظیم متن
            txt2.setText(" which one do you want to show?");

             Button btn1help2 = (Button) dl.findViewById(R.id.bt1help2);
                btn1help2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {


            String array_spinner[];
            array_spinner=new String[5];

            array_spinner[0]="letter_one";
            array_spinner[1]="letter_2";
            array_spinner[2]="letter_3";
            array_spinner[3]="letter_4";
            array_spinner[4]="letter_5";
            array_spinner[5]="letter_6";
            array_spinner[6]="letter_7";
            array_spinner[7]="letter_8";
            array_spinner[8]="letter_9";
            array_spinner[9]="letter_10";


            Spinner s = (Spinner) dl.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);


            s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

how can change it to scrollable spinner?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: do you know why you are doing `new String[5]`?

Comment: yes
It was my mistake,
I didnt pay attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Put your `RelativeLayout` inside `ScrollView` because it just can have one child.

```
    <ScrollView>
      <RelativeLayout>
        .... other views
      </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: sorry but i didnt undrestand ? have one child?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this array_spinner=new String[5]; you set size of 5 items but you put 10 so, you initialize the array this String array_spinner[]; array_spinner=new String[10];